# SELECT first element of column of type list in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with a field called 'ids' that represents a list. I would like to execute a SELECT query that retrieves the first value of the list. Any ideas of what function to use, i.e. what should fn be:

```
SELECT fn(ids) from <TABLE>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data and also which DBMS and version are you using?

Comment: What is the format of the list column?

Comment: Your table has _columns_, not fields!

Comment: Never, ever store comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble!

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 ids from <Table>
```

or, of you have another column to order by,

```
select top 1 ids from <table> order by <ordercol>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP(1) Ids FROM <TABLE>
```

Comment: Hi usenNath, congratulations on your first answer. if you give any answer please add a description of a solution with some example so, it will easy to understand.